# Makefile fails on ubuntu 14.04 - undefined reference

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

I can't get this Makefile to work. This is the simplest example. Below is the code and error:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main(){
    hello();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void hello(void){
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

hello.h

```
#ifndef _HELLO_H
#define _HELLO_H

void hello(void);

#endif
```

Makefile

```
CC=gcc -Wall -pedantic 

prog: main.o hello.o
    ${CC} -o prog main.o hello.o
main.o: main.c hello.h
    ${CC} -o main.o main.c
hello.o: hello.c hello.h
    ${CC} -o hello.o hello.c
```

Error:

```
/tmp/ccuNUbQK.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `hello'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Simply writing

```
gcc -o prog main.c hello.c
```

works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to tell the compiler that you only want a partial compilation (i.e. no linking) when generating the object files.

```
    ${CC} -c -o xxx.o xxx.c
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now:)

@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams
This is the first time I'm doing this. I will learn all about it eventually.